# download zip file with angularjs and filesaver

Tags: angularjs, filesaver.js

I need to download a file zip, created on my server, I have read several answers about this topic but my browser keeps downloading only 15 byte of the file zip. This is the callback function of the $http.post request

```
function(resp){
                          var blob = new Blob([resp], {type: "application/octet-stream", responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
                          console.log('response',resp)
                          FileSaver.saveAs(blob,'registrazioni.zip',(err) => {
                              console.log('saved success,error',err);
                          }
```

this is the request:

```
$http.post('/api/download/',data, {
          dataType : "binary",
          processData : false,
          responseType:'arraybuffer'})
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Read that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31172730/1737410 And specially {responseType: "arraybuffer"}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code snippet, it worked for me.

```
var file = response.blob();
```

Then using the FileSaver make saveAs call:

```
file.then(function(file){
   saveAs(file, "registrazioni.zip");
});
```