# Download a zip file in reactjs without any plugins

Tags: reactjs, zip, gzip

I am getting a response from a rest api whose `Content-Type` is `text/html` and `Content-Encoding` is `gzip`.

I tried to download it using blob

```
const blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/gzip' });
const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const a = document.createElement('a'); 
a.href = downloadUrl;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

But the downloaded gz file was not able to open (seems to be corrupted).
can some one help me with downloading zip file in `reactjs`.

Edit: require a solution without using any external plugins

Comment: You can use JsZip on Client Side

Answer (score 5):

you can use [`jszip`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) npm module.

For example:

```
var zip = new JSZip();

zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");
var img = zip.folder("images"); //images is the folder which will be zip

img.file("smile.gif", imgData, {base64: true});

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {

    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
});
```

To use it without jszip, you can try the following code:

```
function str2bytes (str) {
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length);
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

and its usage:

```
var blob = new Blob([str2bytes(myData)], {type: "application/zip"});
saveAs(blob, "data.zip");
```

But `jszip` is a better alternative approach.

Comment: I dont want to use any external plugins in my application due to some reasons

Comment: oh I just seen you have updated your question.  well you can check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127849/how-to-save-binary-data-of-zip-file-in-javascript

Comment: jszip is no good for big files. Sometimes it returns empty files.

Comment: so @MannyAlvarado that's why you downvoted? In actuality on SO, the answer depends on the OP requirement.